# How can I push to Launchpad if port 22 is blocked?

Tags: networking, ssh, git, launchpad, source-code

I am programming at McDonalds, and need to push some code up to Launchpad.

```
git push origin master

ssh: connect to host git.launchpad.net port 22: No route to host
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

But they have blocked Port 22. Any way to get around this?

I'm on 20.04.

There are solutions present for github and gitlab here:

> https://stackoverflow.com/a/8081292/2158002

```
Host github.com
  Hostname ssh.github.com
  Port 443
```

I have not been able to replicate this yet for Launchpad. My attempt here:

```
Host git.launchpad.net
  Hostname ssh.launchpad.net
  Port 443
```

produces

```
ssh: Could not resolve hostname ssh.launchpad.net: Name or service not known
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Comment: Either way, it says "no route to host". If the port were blocked, I don't think that's the message you'd get.

Comment: If your employer blocks port 22 I am not sure this is an Ubuntu problem. If you have no internet, or launched is down temporarily as "no route to host" suggest, once again this is not an Ubuntu problem. Finally, 19.10 is not supported here anymore.

Comment: It is rather common for companies to block port 22. I do not know of a workaround.

Comment: Is it OK to use https?

Comment: @muru depending on the network configuration, then that *could* be the mechanism that it responds with.

Comment: You say you're at McDonalds.  Are you an employee at McDonalds or are you just at McDonalds for the public wifi?  It is not uncommon to see public networks block port 22, etc. if they go through a content / interception filter.  In this case, "name or service not known" means your DNS is fubar.  Open a web browser and go to cnn.com or a non-HTTPS site and *accept* the terms of use then you should have full Internet access.

Comment: @ThomasWard Just a customer. No, they block specific ports. and leave the common browsing ones for http and https open.

Answer (score 1):

We may add pushing to git.launchpad.net over HTTPS in future, but it's not a feature we have right now, unfortunately.

Your best bet is probably to look for a proxy that you can use to tunnel your SSH traffic over a port that your employer's firewall allows.